# How can I set a default value when incorrect/invalid input is entered?

Tags: c++, default

The direction in the project states the following:

“For the activity level, if the input is not valid, print a message and tell the user you are assuming that they are sedentary.”

The following is my current code, I am trying to get it to default to `"Sedentary"` which the user can input as SA or sa. The default for an invalid input is supposed to make the program default to sedentary, and I am a little confused whether I am on the right track or not.

```
else if (gender == 'F' || gender == 'f') {
    cout << "Please enter your Height in inches. (You may include a decimal) ";
    cin  >> height;

    cout << "Please enter your Weight in pounds as a whole number. ";
    cin  >> weight;

    cout << "Please enter your Age in years. ";
    cin  >> age;
    cout << endl;

    if (activity_level = 'SA' || activity_level = 'sa' || activity_level = 'LA' || activity_level = 'la' || 
        activity_level = 'MA' || activity_level = 'ma' || activity_level = 'VA' || activity_level = 'va') {
        cout << "Please enter your activity level." << endl << endl;
        cout << "You may enter one of the following choices." << endl << endl;
        cout << "Sedentary (Little or no exercise)   \"SA\" or \"sa\" " << endl;
        cout << "Lightly Active (Light exercise/sports 1-3 days a week)   \"LA\" or \"la\" " << endl;
        cout << "Moderately Active (Moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days a week)   \"MA\" or \"ma\" " << endl;
        cout << "Very Active (Hard exercise/sports 6-7 days a week)   \"VA\" or \"va\" " << endl << endl;
        cout << "Enter your activity level now. ";
        cin  >> activity_level;
        cout << endl;
    }
    // Output for the  message to defualt to Sedentary if you do not select activity level throught he proper input.
    else {
        activity_level =
        cout << "I'm sorry I did not recogonize that activity level. We will assume a sedentary amount of exercise. "
    }
}
```

Basically I am wondering, if what I am doing; the use of another if statement within the `else if` statement, will work out, and I am wondering if the way I have it set up at the moment will produce the required result.

Comment: `activity_level = 'SA'` does an *assignment* to `activity_level` and not a comparison.  `activity_level == "SA"` would be a comparison.

Comment: Why are you checking the activity_level before the user has a chance to input it?

Comment: Good point, I saw that mistake at least after I posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to default to `SA` then you could do this:

```
    //Assume activity_level has had something assigned to it, to compare to.

    if (activity_level == "SA" || activity_level == "sa" || activity_level == "LA" || activity_level == "la" || 
        activity_level == "MA" || activity_level == "ma" || activity_level == "VA" || activity_level == "va")
    {
        //Do stuff if input is valid
    }
    // Output for the  message to defualt to Sedentary if you do not select activity level throught he proper input.
    else
    {
        activity_level = "SA";
        std::cout << "I'm sorry I did not recogonize that activity level. We will assume a sedentary amount of exercise.";
    }
```

Also something with single quotes can only be a single `char`, anything else needs double quotes around it, because it's a string.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You must check the variable `activity_level' *after* it has been assigned a value. Also you should use == to make comparisons. And you could use the ! operator to negate a condition.